# kendo, typescript - Move dataBound event to a separate function to reuse

Tags: typescript, kendo-ui

I have next code for the kendo multiselect element.

```
var newitemtext: string;
var multiselect = t.sender.element.find("#redirectUris-multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
dataTextField: "text",
dataValueField: "value",
change() {
    ClientApplicationsGrid.prototype.changeFuncForMultiselect(this, multiselect);
},
dataBound() {
    if ((newitemtext || this._prev) && newitemtext !== this._prev) {
        newitemtext = this._prev;

        let dataitems = this.dataSource.data();

        for (let i = 0; i < dataitems.length; i++) {
            const dataItem = dataitems[i];

            if (dataItem.value !== dataItem.text) {
                this.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
            }
        }

        dataitems = this.dataSource.data();
        let found = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < dataitems.length; i++) {
            const dataItem = dataitems[i];
            if (dataItem.value === newitemtext) {
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if (!found && newitemtext !== "") {
            this.dataSource.add(
                { text: newitemtext + " (Add New)", value: newitemtext });
            this.open();
        }
    }
}}).data("kendoMultiSelect");
```

I've successfully move code from change() event to a separate function ClientApplicationsGrid.prototype.changeFuncForMultiselect(this, multiselect).
I need somehow to do same for the dataBound() event, because I will have almost the same multiselect in another place and I want to reuse the code. But when I did the same as for change() I got "Maximum stack trace call". I guess it is because I use newitemtext variable inside dataBound(), but I am not sure.

Could somebody help me with this stuff, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataSource.remove()` and `dataSource.add()` are triggering "dataBound" event ([example](https://dojo.telerik.com/oROXizet/3)), so your code is recursive and that's why you got error "Maximum stack trace call". You should not change your dataSource on dataBound event.

Comment: ahh.. It seems it is impossible to do what I want?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to do. Why do you change dataSource on dataBound?

Comment: @ЕвгенийТымчишин, I think you should get your data by get request, validate it on success callback (add or remove some items), then you can bind it to your dataSource.